# JAAS authentifaction fails with Tomcat 7 without errormessage

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, jaas

Related to the post of another user ([issue with JAAS authentication on Tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917885/issue-with-jaas-authentication-on-tomcat-7)) I try to use JASS for authentifaction in my JSF application.

Unfortunately I am always directed to the loginFailed.xhtml page if I try to log in.

I use Tomcat7, JSF 2.2 and a Derby database for storing users/passwords.

Here is an excerpt from my server.xml:

```
            <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost"
            unpackWARs="true">

            <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications 
                Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
            <!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" 
                /> -->

            <!-- Access log processes all example. Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html 
                Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log."
                suffix=".txt" />

            <Context docBase="socialanalysis" path="/socialanalysis"
                reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:socialanalysis">
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
                    driverName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver" connectionURL="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/socialanalysis"
                    connectionName="socialanalysis" connectionPassword="socialanalysis"
                    userTable="users" userNameCol="username" userCredCol="password"
                    userRoleTable="users_roles" roleNameCol="rolename"/>
            </Context>

        </Host>
```

Excepert from my web.xml:

```
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>secured</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginFailed.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

I followed this tutorial to create the database: 
http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/07/07/configure-jdbcrealm-jaas-for-mysql-and-tomcat-7-with-form-based-authentication/

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: How do your DB tables and their contents look like?

Comment: What is url-pattern of your Faces Servlet? if you use /* it can prevent to access j_security_check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @cy3er. I have three tables (USERS, ROLES, USERS_ROLES). USERS consists of two columns (USERNAME, PASSWORD). In USERS there is one entry ("benutzer", "passwort"). ROLES has only one column ROLENAME with one entry ("user"). And finally USERS_ROLES has the columns USERNAME and ROLENAME. USERS_ROLES has the entry "benutzer, user"

Comment: Thank you for your answer @bhdrk. My url-pattern of my Faces Servlet is configured as followed:

     <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

I am not absolutely sure why it works now, but I think it has been working after I added http-method attributes to my web.xml security configuration:

```
        <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>secured</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
```